# Cannot retrieve correct height of html5 video element after using webkit transform scaleY

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, html5-video

Im trying to make a html5 video element "responsive". Its allmost 100% width, but it just needed a little extra width and the clip had a bit too much height aswell.  So i did the following:

```
css: 
    video {
         width:100%;
         height:auto; //seemingly does nothing
    }

js:
$('video').css("-webkit-transform-origin","50% 0 0");
$('video').css("-webkit-transform","scaleY(0.75)");
```

the problem with this solution is the following:

[image: Me inspecting the video element]

[image: Me selecting the "next" element in the DOM]

So basically there is just a huge gap here with the video element saying that the height is 776px, but if i do:

```
jQuery('video').height()
```

That gives back the height before the scaleY, about 1000px, and no matter what i do to retrieve the height of the video element e.g. innerHeight, outerHeight offsetHeight etc. it will allways return the old height of the element before the scaleY. So.. my solution was to wrap the video in a container element:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 video-container">
     <video  autoplay loop>
         <source src={{ video }} type="video/mp4">
     </video>
</div>
```

And then select that outer element and set the height to 767px, which actually works, problem just is, that when i open it on my laptop screen, then the 767px is off, then the scaleY on the video element made it more like 567px, so the scaleing obviously takes the screen height into consideration, but im kind of lost at this point. I have some possible solutions:

- Change the clip it self to be at a specific height and use
  mediaqueries to change it, that would improve the quality of the
  video aswell(right now the quality is acceptable though, and i guess i would need ALOT of mediaqueries for this to work. )
- Figure out how to get the result of the scaleY(why isn't this accessible? it has to be), if i can get that height i can just set the container element to the same height and it fixes everything.
- Any other ideas? maybe smt really smart! :)

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely follow or understand the end goal (which might help me help you solve the issue), but regarding getting the scaleY, can you not just get it by multiplying whatever value .height() returns by your scale factor, which seems to be a constant .75? i.e. `jQuery('video').height() * .75` But again, I may be misunderstanding everything. :-)

Comment: What aspect ratio do you want to achieve? 16:9? 4:3?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using:

```
video {
  width: 100%    !important;
  height: auto   !important;
}
```